# Can not import flask pycharm

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__main__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

If i run this i get the following error code:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask' from partially initialized module 'flask' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you installed flask in your environment? if not, follow the steps from the flask documentation on how to install it.

Comment: I have installed flask.

Comment: What is the name of the file you have made?

Comment: Its name is flask.

Comment: You can't name it `flask.py`, or the interpreter will try to import Flask from the file itself, which is what the error you're seeing means. You'll need to rename your Python file.

Answer (score 2):

Circular import error occurs as you are importing same module name as the name of the python script. Rename your file to resolve the issue, never use module names as your file names.