# how to fix flask import eror (there is no Flask in flask)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, flask, pycharm, importerror

i installed flask in the cmd using the pip install flask command and i also tested it in the cmd and it works.
But when i go to pycharm all the modules i download using pip are for some reason in lib/site_packages
instead of just being in site_packages.[the lib folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIBDi.png)
and then i do "from flask import Flask"
and it says that " cannot import name 'Flask' from 'flask' (C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\flask.py)"
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK6h8.png)
[there is no Flask in flask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg21Q.png)

Comment: Please post all relevant code and/or errors as text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not import flask pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128312/can-not-import-flask-pycharm)

Answer (score 1):

Change the py file name to anything else. naming your flask file as flask.py will create a namespace conflict.